# Efficiency of data:image in CSS

Tags: css, background-image

Was wondering if this

```
background:#092542 url('data:image/png;base64, ....') center top no-repeat;
```

is more efficient than

```
background:#092542 url('myimage.png') center top no-repeat;
```

I'm trying to cut down on load times and if this would help out, great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the image is only being used once, on one page, then it might give a very slight (probably not noticeable) difference in loading (faster), however it also means the browser can't cache the image, so if it's used on another page it'll have to be loaded again, which means double (triple, etc) the data is being transferred.

Generally, it's not worth it, although maybe if it's a micro site it could be easier, but not by much.

Comment: Well I found this, finally: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#Disadvantages

Answer (score 0):

Data URI images ARE cached. However, the caching of the image is dependent on how the file that is contained in is cached.  If the stylesheet that includes the Data URI image is being cached, then the image will not be downloaded until the stylesheet itself is redownloaded.

I'd also recommend this [post](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/10/27/data-uris-explained/) explaining Data URI's further, especially the section on performance.